# Configure Tomcat to use disk memory

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6

I use Tomcat 6.0 and frequently receive out of memory exceptions.

I've set memory to `-xmX1024m` . I'm unable to allocate more memory to Tomcat due to memory restrictions of my machine. Is there a configuration or VM parameter that allows to increase this memory setting, but use disk memory augmented with RAM memory ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  This is what virtual memory of the operating system is for.

Note that the garbage collector in the JVM may search through all the memory allocated to the JVM looking for live objects meaning that performance may be very badly influenced if too much memory is swapped to disk.

Add additional swap space, but be very careful.

You may also want to consider using a web server with a smaller footprint, or investigate if your web app uses more memory than you expect it to.

Comment: "This is what virtual memory of the operating system is for." Do you mean the OS will swap file to disk automatically if memory is running out ? "additional swap space" is this a tomcat param ? I'm using Windows OS

Comment: For Windows you might find http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-is-virtual-memory#1TC=windows-7 interesting.

Comment: You do not want you JVM to start using swap. Performance will drop through the floor if that happens.